# How to Build Hydrogen Atoms in MOE using SVL

Tags: computational-chemistry, software, hydrogen

I'm working on automating a process in MOE using SVL commands. I've got pretty much everything worked out, except I can't seem to find anything for building hydrogen atoms using an SVL command (equivalent to Edit->Build->Hydrogens->Add Hydrogens).

Is there a method to do this, and if so what is it?

Edit: MOE (Molecular Operating Environment), SVL (Scientific Vector Language)

Comment: Please remember that ChemSE enjoys a broad spectrum of readers, early and seasoned in the study of chemistry, *including* those with interest but without formal education of chemistry, too.  There is nothing wrong using abbreviations in a question, however consider that many readers might not *yet* encountered them.  Both as act of courtesy as well as to limit *potential* misunderstanding (because one abbreviation may have a different meaning to different readers) *first explain* the thing, *then use* the intended abbreviation.  Specific to your question: what «MOE» and «SVL» stand for?

Comment: While MOE and SVL are technically acronyms (Molecular Operating Environment and Scientific Vector Language respectively) MOE and SVL are much more common usage. I have no problem adding it, but to me adding those would be additional unhelpful information. Additionally if someone does not know what MOE and SVL are from context they are unlikely to be able to help with my question. Do you disagree?

Comment: I agree that the addition of the «full name» of these abbreviations will be common parlance for those «in the field» *likely* to help with your question, and other readers stay observers.  The potential benefit indeed is aimed for the readers *not yet* familiar with these, who might be intrigued if these may be beneficial for their work.  For their length, to keep reading your question facile, I footnote largely would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer: `_EditH 'addH'`

As I continued researching how to finish up my project, I came across a tutorial describing the behavior of Menus in MOE. (Tutorial download available from https://www.chemcomp.com/moe/help/2018/index_crs.html). All menus in MOE have their behavior defined by a file within the MOE installation directory. ("\$MOE/menu/moe-menus" where "\$MOE" is the MOE installation directory.)

By following the configuration file you can determine the exact SVL command used upon the selection of any menu item. You then can use that command in the SVL Commands window.